# Faulty NXT Motor

Tags: nxt, motor, repair

I have a motor that prevents the program from running. It simply allows a few slow movements forward with stops in between. It seems very stiff to rotate manually. Any way I can repair this motor?

Comment: This happened to me a long time ago. I ended up just getting a new one to replace it. I'm wanting to say that disassembling a motor beyond a certain point makes it impossible to reassemble, so I'm not sure how practical it would be to repair a motor.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with HaydenStudios, it is impossible to disassemble completely NXT motor without breaking the orange axle hub. You can nonetheless half-open it enough to see what's happening inside (you need a Torx screwdriver - T10 size if I remember well - to open it. See photos here http://philohome.com/nxtmotor/nxtmotor.htm.
Anyway, first try to see what LEGO support can do for you!

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem with the RCX about a month ago.  Check the wires for shorts or fraying, and if you can open the case and look for shorts in there.  I fixed my fraying wire with electrical tape.

Comment: Glad to hear you could fix your problem with electrical tape. I doubt that will help this "Faulty NXT Motor", since "very stiff to rotate manually" is an indication of broken gears inside to motor.

Comment: Mine was also "stiff to rotate" until I fixed it